# Windows 10 Live tiles not showing on large size mode

Tags: windows, windows-10

I am facing a problem with Windows 10 Apps Live Tiles.

It works well when using a medium sized tile but not with a large or wide app. How do I enable Live Tiles with a wide or large size

[image: Medium Sized Tile and another Wide Tile]

Comment: So if you change the size of the News tile, to something smaller, it starts working.  Is this every tile, because a given tile must support `Live Tile`, it doesn't just happen automatically.

Comment: Yup exactly. I tried this with `News` and `Weather` which both support live tiles

Comment: But do they support. Live Tile, at those larger sizes.  I am not at a machine where I confirm this is intended behavior or not.

Comment: yes they do: http://www.howtogeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/599x628xweather.png.pagespeed.gp+jp+jw+pj+js+rj+rp+rw+ri+cp+md.ic.T0hq9hO7zQ.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem.

Solution found on How-To-Geek's article found [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/242068/how-to-configure-the-windows-10-weather-app) which says:

> Normally, this tile should display the current temperature with a
>   snapshot of the upcoming forecast that’s updated every few minutes–as
>   shown above.
>
> However, users on the official Windows 10 forum have reported that
>   sometimes, after resizing the Weather app on their Start menu, the
>   icon stops showing live updates, even with repeated restarts. So far
>   there have been a number of proposed fixes for the problem, but like
>   most solutions to Windows bugs, they only seem to work for a select
>   number of people at a time. Some include:
>
> - Running the System File Checker tool (i.e. `sfc /scannow`)
> - Changing your display’s DPI settings to 100%, 125%, or 150%
> - Killing a process in your Task Manager called “Windows RT OOP Server”
>     Two years have passed since people
>     started complaining about the problem, but Microsoft still hasn’t
>     revealed any plans about a patch in the pipeline that could resolve
>     it. We’ll be sure to amend this article if a hotfix is ever released.

Mine was changing display DPI settings to one of the default settings.

Comment: Arrrrgh. 100% is TOO small, 125% is TOO big. Why hasn't Microsoft fixed it yet??? That's a great feature!

Answer (score 0):

Please turn off custom scaling.

Go to Setting>System>Display>Scale and layout

Answer (score -1):

if anyone is still struggling getting their tiles to work with custom scaling, try disabling the option "let windows try to correct apps with unsharp view" under advanced scaling options

[advanced scaling options in win10 2004 DE-DE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Aji4.jpg)